# How to configure external Nuget source ( Packages ) in Azure DevOps build pipe line

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, build-pipeline

I have used my own nuget package in my solution for this we added package source to nuget package manager to my solution. From visual studio my solution in perfectly building and working as we excepted.

When we try to create a build pipe line , we have a build issues due to my package source is not present in pipeline Task.

How to add / configure my own nuget package to Azure DevOps build pipeline

### [error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects

```
Unable to find version '0.9.2.15772' of package 'MyValidater'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package ''MyValidater'.0.9.2.XXXXX' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.)
```

### [error]Packages failed to restore

Finishing: NuGet restore

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to add your registry in the Nuget restore task

Comment: Have you checked the following reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a nuget.config-file which refers to the package/feed you're using. From within the pipeline you can then restore the packages listed in this config-file.
This has been described here:
https://mbraekman.github.io/2020/04/25/Access-a-NuGet-package-hosted-in-a-private-feed/